# Costs of AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm wanting to host a simple blog on AWS via Docker containers.  I've gone the route of creating an EC2 instance via this link https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#LaunchInstanceWizard:

I created an instance of type Amazon Linux AMI and it's a t2.micro.

How do I know if this is a low-cost way to host my blog?  What are the fees?  How do I know that I have 1 year free trial?

The reason I ask is because I looked at [this](https://www.docker.com/aws) on the docker site and then when clicking the [Get Started with AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B014VG1SIG/ref=sp_mpg_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-4//ref=_ptnr_web_Docker) link on that page, it brought me to a page that started talking about large costs...is this for larger servers that is not related to the free 1 year EC2 instance I'm trying to run for a simple blog?

I'm just looking for a cheap AWS instance to host my blog, maybe a few dollars a month with very small amount of traffic and want to make sure I'm doing this right in terms of creating and setting up my server since I do want to use docker to deploy my blog in a container.

Comment: There are some [possibly] cheaper alternatives.  A friend of my went with http://www.hostgator.com/ You can use VPS hosting, which gives you a virtual linux machine and you get root access and can install whatever you need.  Prices are a fixed fee/mo and there are various tiers.

Comment: I really want to use AWS, so I just need some guidance in how to navigate the costs here for running a simple blog, that will be pushed via docker.  My friend keeps telling me running a site on AWS, a simple site like this should be very cheap.  But if I start using EC2 does that change the ballgame, meaning you're no longer dealing with petty stuff and you have to start paying big time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you go with t2.nano instance which will cost you just $5/month + nominal data xfer cost. Later if you find the instance size not sufficient, you can upgrade the instance to t2.micro to t2.small to m3.medium etc., just by clicking few buttons.

Use this calculator: [SIMPLE MONTHLY CALCULATOR](http://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html) to find the approximate cost.

Comment: this was exactly what I was looking for, did not know it existed as I'm a bit new to AWS, thanks!